# How to convert string to decimal with specific number of digits

Tags: c#

I have a small question regarding Math.Round function.
I need the string "12.123456" to be rounded at 4 decimals. I used:

```
 Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(pData), 4).ToString()
```

where pData is defined as string, but the values are decimal with 7 decimals.
My problem is that I expected to get every time the exact 4 decimals, but for some values it gives me only 2 (eg. 12.12 instead of 12.1200).
How can I change in order to always get the needed 4 decimals?
Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k) instead:

```
pDate.ToString("0.0000")
```

or

```
pDate.ToString("n4")
```